# Purchase part 3

Tags: java

Using the codes below, this lets me input codes, name and description. However, after entering purchase. The problem is that It can't display the details I want to show using the right code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        String q;
        String ans;
        String itemCounts = "";
        String name="",descriptions = "";

        do {
            System.out.print("Item code:");
            itemCounts += "" + a.next() + "\n";

            System.out.print("Item name:");
            name += "" + a.next() + "\n";

            System.out.print("des:");
            descriptions += "" + a.next() + "\n";

            System.out.println("Do you want to add more? yes or no:");
            ans = a.next();
        } while (ans.equals("yes"));


        System.out.print("enter 1 to purchase :");
        x = a.nextInt();

        if(x==1){

            System.out.print("enter code:");
            q = a.next();

            if(q==itemCounts){

                String[] b = itemCounts.split("\n");
                String[] nm = name.split("\n");
                String[] des = descriptions.split("\n");

                for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {

                    System.out.println("Item name:" + nm[i]);
                    System.out.println("Item description:" + des[i]);

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: And whats the exception/problem?

Comment: the problem is that i can't display the details i input once i enter the right code.

Comment: sorry for the errors. i'm a newbie here.

Answer (score 2):

`q==itemCounts`
should be
`q.equals(itemCounts)`

Because `q` and `itemCounts` both are `String`. `==` tests for reference equality and `.equals()` tests for value equality.

Also `itemCounts += "" + a.next() + "\n";` should be `itemCounts += a.next();`

This will help : [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: however it works only for single input.